# Using mapbox to implement lighting effects?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I use mapbox.gl.js + postgrepsql+mapnik+ mapbox vector tile;
this is my map:
[image]

but I want this, **The point of overlap is brighter**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [heatmap-layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/heatmap-layer/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such effect by using multiply or overlay blending. How you can implement that depends on your style. Wikipedia offers some background at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes